# How to parse the web content using HttpURLConnection and TagNode class?

Tags: java, http, url, web

I would like to take some data from www.groupon.pl website. To do this I used code below:

```
String currentUrl = "https://www.groupon.pl/browse/radom";
URL urlObj = new URL(currentUrl);
HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) urlObj.openConnection();
urlConnection.addRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; rv:43.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/43.0");
urlConnection.connect();
final HtmlCleaner cleaner = new HtmlCleaner();
final TagNode tagNodeRoot = cleaner.clean(urlConnection.getInputStream());
```

The problem is that after the last line:

```
final TagNode tagNodeRoot = cleaner.clean(urlConnection.getInputStream());
```

The program doesn't want go further. I think that maybe the problem is with:

```
urlConnection.addRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; rv:43.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/43.0");
```

Or maybe I use some and old API which is not supported any more? I use debugger and it doesn't stepping out. When I run this code normally without any debugger it also stops. No error at the console. I don't know maybe it is waiting for the response. Could you tell me what is wrong? Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't want to go further"? Do you get error at that line? Does it hang? Is debugger not stepping out?

Comment: Debugger doesn't stepping out. No error at the console. I don't know maybe it is waiting for the response.

Comment: Does it run properly though? Or does the run get stuck too? Debuggers can stop for several reasons. Also, is this code running as a standalone app or part of some webapp?

Comment: When I not using debugger just only run the integration test it is also stop. Generally it is a web app, but this module is tested by integration test like standalone app.